# Question about the limits of definite integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let me take an example that I've come across while studying Fourier series,

We all know that

$$\int_{-a}^{a} \sin \left( \frac{n\pi x}{a} \right) dx = 2 \int_{0}^{a} \sin \left(\frac{n \pi x}{a} \right) dx$$

So why is it that when evaluating both sides separately the results seem to differ?

I. $$\int_{-a}^{a} \sin \left( \frac{n\pi x}{a} \right) dx =  -\frac{a}{n \pi} \cos \left( \frac{n\pi x}{a} \right)_{-a}^{a} = -\frac{a}{n \pi} \left[ \cos (n\pi) - \cos(-n \pi) \right] = 0$$

II. $$2 \int_{0}^{a} \sin \left(\frac{n \pi x}{a} \right) dx = -\frac{2a}{n \pi} \cos \left( \frac{n\pi x}{a} \right)_{0}^{a} = - \frac{2a}{n\pi} \left[ \cos(n \pi) - 1\right] = \begin{cases}
 0, & \text{if } n\text{ is even} \\ 
 \frac{4a}{n\pi}, & \text{if } n \text{is odd}
\end{cases}$$

My question is, how can I also obtain $\frac{4a}{n\pi}$ from a direct integration from $-a$ to $a$ ? The expression $\left[ \cos (n\pi) - \cos(-n \pi) \right]$ seems to be always $0$, right? Regardless of $n$ being even or odd. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: The "We all know that" is wrong. The integral of an odd function over an interval $[-a,a]$ is always $0$. The integral over $[0,a]$ need not be $0$.

Comment: I think the assertion following the "we all know that" is not true, to begin with. The sine function is _odd_, so what we can easily see is that the integral is $0$... _not_ that the integrand is an "even" function, as that first displayed equality would suggest.

Comment: By the way, just to emphasize that $\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)dx = \int_{-a}^{0} f(x)dx + \int_{0}^{a} f(x)dx$ and if $f(-x)=-f(x)$ which is the case for the sine function, then $\int_{-a}^{0} f(x)dx = -\int_{0}^{-a} f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{a} f(x)dx$

Comment: @DanielFischer I see, but then why does my textbook makes the substitution then? If as you said, the integral of an odd function is always $0$ at $[-a,a]$ then it could have never been substituted to $[0,a]$ and yield a value other than zero. What's going on?

Answer (score 3):

The statement after "We all know that" is completely false. $\sin(cx)$ for any $c$ is an *odd* function, so any integral on an interval symmetric around $0$ will give 0. The correct result is:

$$\int_{-a}^a\sin(cx)dx=\int_{0}^a\sin(cx)dx+\int_{-a}^0\sin(cx)dx,$$

and now do a change of variables on the second integral $u=-x$ and use the fact that $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$.